VScode: inserting new line inside an array suddenly changes spacing
it seems that the behavior only occurs while there is already a entry defined in the array, not while it is empty
but while there is a entry defined, inserting a new line moves the table brace to my cursor and changes the indent to only use two spaces (my editor is set to use 4 spaces for indents)
inserting another new line after that will remove all indentation entirely
for context, it is only a new behavior and has never happened in the past
i expected it to simply continue adding new lines between my cursor and the brace, keeping the indentation without moving the brace relative to the cursor
i searched inside vscode's editor settings, however i was unable to find the exact setting that could cause such a specific problem
edit: i notice another related problem that has started happening at the same time i noticed this behavior, instead the editor entirely refuses to add any indentation upon pressing enter

for my case, it seems that it is caused by some setting inside the Lua extension (by sumneko)

a temporary solution is to simply downgrade the lua extension to a older one, i downgraded to a version released 2mo ago and the behavior no longer occurs
